# update url variables through a link

Tags: php

How I can update url variables through a link?
That's the url for example:

```
http://www.example.com/?brand=1&maxprice=300&page=1
```

The link needs to change the page variable content from 1 to 2. 
So how can I do that? How can I update url variables using a link.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
<?php
if($_GET['page']==1)
{
header("location:http://www.example.com/?brand=1&maxprice=300&page=2");
}
```

Comment: But it's static, what if the values of maxprice and brand would be diffrent?so every time I click next page it will change them into 1 and 300?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $pageNum = $_GET['page']; ?>
<a href="http://www.example.com/?brand=1&maxprice=300&page=<?php echo $pageNum++; ?>">Next page (pg. <?php echo $pageNum; ?>)</a>
```

Would turn into:

```
Next page (pg. 2)
```

For "Previous page", just swap the `++` with `--`.  You'll want to do some error checking too though (verify not null, not < 0, not > total #, etc).

Your question is pretty open-ended though so you can go a few different ways with this.

Comment: But it's static, what if the values of maxprice and brand would be diffrent?so every time I click next page it will change them into 1 and 300?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean if the user changed some input fields on the page.  If that's the case, you use Javascript to get the values not PHP.  Or use a form.

Comment: I do use a form.. I got a variable that has the current url address, so all I need is to change the page value inside it but i don't know how..

Comment: join chat and message me in the PHP room